# OpenAPI @RequestBody variables of type Map are not populated

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger-ui, openapi

I've a simple POST API where the @RequestBody contains a variable of type HashMap.

The problem is that the variable "myMap" is never populated.

Swagger UI shows the entry field correctly, with corresponding default values.
I also added the a static block in the Configuration file, otherwise Swagger UI doesn't show the entry field of type Map.

What is needed so that the variable myMap is populated ?

Config class

> ```
> static {
>     SpringDocUtils.getConfig().removeRequestWrapperToIgnore(java.util.Map.class);
> }
> ```

Controller class

> ```
> @RequestMapping(value = "/process/start",method = RequestMethod.POST)
> public void startProcess1(
>         @RequestBody(description = "HashMap of strings", required = true) HashMap<String, String> myMap)  {
>     Assert.notEmpty(myMap, "map may not be empty");
> }
> ```

Swagger UI

[image]

pom.xml

> ```
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
>         <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
>         <version>1.5.12</version>
>     </dependency>
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that I used the wrong annotation. @RequestBody is a class which resides in two packages :

1. org.springframework.web.bind.annotation
2. io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.parameters

I used the annotation from package **io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.parameters**  which is wrong.
The correct annotation is located in package **org.springframework.web.bind.annotation**

Comment: saved me...  i am so grateful !!!  thank you !!!